# Why do these two Tensorflow operations not have the same result?

Tags: math, tensorflow

I am making a tensorflow graph, and the final step is a simple mean squared error calculation. Some of the inputs are padding, which I am masking out using the tensor `loss_mask`. This tensor is mostly 1's, with a few 0's at the end.

The following operation calculates the mean squared error, where the masked out inputs count as zero error.

```
error_squared = loss_mask * tf.pow(expected_outputs_reshaped - network_outputs, 2)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(error_squared)
```

The problem is that, if many outputs are masked out, then the average loss seems much lower than it should, since these masked out inputs count as zero error. So, I tried the following code to correct this:

```
error_squared = loss_mask * tf.pow(expected_outputs_reshaped - network_outputs, 2)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(error_squared) / tf.reduce_sum(loss_mask)
```

If `loss_mask` is all 1's, then these two things should result in the same thing. However, they are not. For the first, I am getting correct values, which are all between 0 and 1. For the second, I am getting values in the hundreds. Why are these two not the same thing?

I have verified that `tf.reduce_sum(loss_mask)` equals the number of elements in `error_squared`.

Comment: yon can try `loss = tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(error_squared),tf.reduce_sum(loss_mask) `

Comment: @TianjinGu That did the exact same thing

Comment: Could you try to find specific values of expected_outputs_reshaped and network_outputs that result in the different values? So its easier to repro. Thanks!